# Could antimatter be "negative matter"?

Tags: antimatter, warp-drives

This question is inspired by [an answer on WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/49203/11664).

The question on worldbuilding is about the Alcubierre Drive, and the answer is a good one, pointing out that it requires "negative matter", which we have never observed and is hard to reconcile with current theory. However, in one of the comments, someone states

> Antimatter *could* be negative matter, but we haven't produced enough of it to find out. (I.e it goes boom before we have time to see which way it falls.)

This doesn't square with my limited non-physicist understanding of antimatter & negative matter. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, antimatter falls down under our current theories, and it would be extremely surprising if it didn't. It _could_ fall up but this would overturn fundamental aspects of GR or the SM.

Comment: @knzhou  silly question,  but if antimatter did fall up, and I'm  sure it doesn't, would it's tracks not be foreshortened, compared to normal matter , say an electron positron pair, on the early cloud chamber photo plates, right up to the present day detectors?

Comment: A negative mass is sometimes associated to _dark_ matter (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass)

Comment: @Phoenix87 : dark energy and inflation ? For dark matter, the wiki page is ambiguous. I don't see how to link the far stars rotation speeds, the reason why dark matter had been invented, to the model of signed matter.

Comment: This question belongs to the "does AM falls up" line. First, the OP asked a perfectly good question - with the best intent -, but without knowing that it was already asked around some hundred times here. What he deserves: 1) clear answer 2) upvote 3) maybe close as dupe _after_ he got his answer (either by the refs, or by the comments, or from the answers). | The closing as "too broad" is meaningless, irrational and impolite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Here I'm going to talk about four types of matter, just to distinguish: matter, antimatter, dark matter, and negative matter.

**Matter**

The dictionary definition of matter is

> physical substance in general, as distinct from mind and spirit; (in physics) that which occupies space and possesses rest mass, especially as distinct from energy.

This was a good definition before the 20th century, but now we know $E = mc^2$ is true, which really makes life confusing. As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter), there isn't really a great definition for matter now, but we'll say an object's mass can be either the stuff that makes up all physical objects, like you and me, or what arises from motion and interaction energies.

Matter is, of course, made of atoms. An atom is composed of protons, neutrons, and electrons. Protons and neutrons are not fundamental; they are composed of quarks and gluons.

**Antimatter**

[Antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter) is composed of the aptly named antiparticles. These antiparticles are positrons (as opposed to electrons), antiprotons, and antineutrons. These antiparticles have the *same mass* as normal particles, but opposite charges, as well as other properties such as lepton and baryon numbers. Collisions between matter and antimatter result in annihilation for both parties.

It is important to note antimatter has the same mass as normal matter in consideration of the other two "types" of matter.

**Dark matter**

We don't really know what [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) is, honestly. We think it makes up around 27% of the mass and energy in the observable universe. We also think it is non-baryonic (as in, it isn't made up of protons and neutrons like normal matter). Some possible candidates for dark matter are hypothetical particles, like [super-symmetric particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) and [axions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion). We think dark matter is different from negative matter.

**Negative matter**

[Negative matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) is matter that has an opposite sign to the mass of normal matter - like -2 grams, or -5 pounds. It would show incredibly strange properties and violate some energy conditions. It is used in speculative theories, such as the construction of warp drives and wormholes. The closest known representative of this very exotic idea is the pseudo-negative pressure density produced by the Casimir effect. Because the standard model doesn't explain gravity and general relativity doesn't explain the EM, strong, or weak forces, a quantum theory of gravity might be needed to really understand how negative matter works.

Looking at these definitions, I think it's pretty clear that antimatter and negative matter are definitely not the same, as antimatter has the same mass but opposite charge, while negative matter has opposite mass.

Hope this helps. I have linked to websites throughout this answer with more information.

Comment: Thank you! That confirms my basic understanding of the situation. I didn't *think* that comment was correct, but I wanted to ask the experts.

Comment: @Kryten, I don't know if I'm an expert, exactly, but I'm glad it helped. Is there anything else I need to add, or is it acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly implausible that antimatter has any "negative" properties, because antiness isn't a thing. The relationship between matter and antimatter is like mirror reflection (precisely, it's [CPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry)). Protons and antiprotons are mirror images *of each other*; neither one is *the* mirror image. Antiprotons get the "anti" prefix merely because they're much less common than protons.

Some particles (photons, for example) are "mirror symmetric", hence antiparticles of themselves. We know that photons fall down (from the bending of starlight by the sun, for example). If antiparticles antigravitate then photons would have to fall up also, which isn't even self consistent.

In the Standard Model, all of the matter particles (fermions) are made of left-handed and right-handed parts coupled through the Higgs interaction. In SO(10) grand unification, all of the left-handed fermions are aspects of the same particle, and the right-handed fermions are their "mirror reflections" (CPT duals), so every matter particle is half "pro" and half "anti", making the idea of antimatter as a class of matter even more nonsensical. We don't know if SO(10) grand unification is correct, but the fact that it's possible to unify all of the fermions suggests that they probably are unified, even if not in exactly that way.

The equivalence principle and [Einstein's rocket argument](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/PVB/Key/relgen3.jpg) also shows that everything must gravitate in the same way. This even includes matter with a negative mass, if it exists. Even in Newtonian gravity negative-mass test particles fall, because the mass of the test particle cancels out of the equation.

So if we found that antiprotons fall up, it would mean that everything we think we understand about particles, that all seems to make sense, is profoundly wrong. I won't say it's *impossible*, but I'd bet on finding leprechauns before I'd bet on this.